# Kitchens: how to properly use in order to still have seeds?

Tags: dwarf-fortress, dwarf-fortress-premium

I'm afraid of using the `Kitchen` because it does not gives me seeds as a result. But having high quality meals is necessary for dwarf happiness.

How can I solve this dilemma?

Is it possible to use <kbd>o</kbd>rders that can take into account how many seeds of 'X' there are  before using 'X' as ingredient?

**Version:** 0.50 (Steam).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can toggle the use of specific plants for cooking in the Kitchen submenu of Work Orders.

[image]

In this example, Cassavas won't be cooked, even though they normally can be. Cave wheat is greyed out because it can't be cooked directly; similarly, lettuce cannot be brewed (which can also be toggled here).

Cooking can be done with alcohol or with flour (and this is the only use for flour) - the process of making these items creates seeds, so cooking in this manner will not destroy seeds like with vegetable cooking.

(Due to a [bug](https://dwarffortress.mantishub.io/view.php?id=2393), actually getting your dorfs to use alcohol for cooking is difficult)

Comment: Thank you for presenting me this screen. I was unaware that it existed. It really can neatly manage my seeds and my seed sources.

Answer (score 4):

It should be possible to use orders to prevent cooking if seed-counts get too low.  I never use the orders screen for that kind of thing so I can't specifically tell you how.

One thing you can do is to have a separate stockpile for each crop you're worried about cooking, and have these smaller stockpiles pull from a larger general stockpile.  Your kitchens are set to only pull from the general stockpile.  This will mean that there will always be some amount of each crop the kitchens can't cook.

Alternatively, just make everything in such high quantities the risk is low.

Comment: "It should be possible to use orders to prevent cooking if seed-counts get too low." This I know how to do. The problem is that it doesn't take into account if it's Macadamia or Plump Helmets!

Comment: "One thing you can do is to have a separate stockpile for each crop you're worried about cooking, and have these smaller stockpiles pull from a larger general stockpile." But wouldn't cooking have a higher priority than hauling seeds, and then the smaller stockpiles having the risk of not receiving the stock first?

Comment: In theory that is a risk, but if you have only one or two kitchens, your haulers will almost certainly get there first.

Answer (score 0):

If one cares only about `Plump Helmet Spawns` and `Dimple Cups Spawns`, one could create this <kbd>o</kbd>rder:

Prepare easy meal 10/10 (if:)

- amount of `unrotten prepared meals` is `less than` 10
- amount of `unrotten cookable items` is `greater than` 10
- amount of `Plump Helmet Spawn` is `at least` 20
- amount of `Dimple Cup Spawn` is `at least` 20

Comment: You used a quote block, but didn't provide a source. Where are you quoting from? Also, avoid using code ticks for normal text (` `) Use either double quotes or italicize and/or bold the parts you think are important

Comment: The ticks are not being used for "important parts", they are demarking options chosen from option lists here and there. That is, text that is not unchangeable, nor is freeform writing. The words make an option, and so are a unit together.