# Manage useless seeds

Tags: dwarf-fortress, dwarf-fortress-premium

1. The answer to [my previous question about how to not exhaust my seeds](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/402363/kitchens-how-to-properly-use-in-order-to-still-have-seeds) worked
   great!
2. The problem is: on the "Labor"->"Kitchen"->"Seeds" menu, [most seed types](https://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/Seed#Seed_List) don't even appear because they are not "Edible raw", nor "Cookable", nor "Farmable", nor "Oil Seed". They are just "Vermin Edible", which means they are just trash to attract rats, but the game won't call it "trash" and let me dispose easily of them.
3. As they don't appear on that menu, I'm left without a central place to order what to do with them.
4. They still mess with my Stocks, inflating the total "Food" I have just because they are seeds.

**Questions:**

1. Can I sell these useless seeds?
2. Are they worth selling? I mean, worth the trouble of storing?
3. How can I know in advance how much they are worth in trade?
4. How can I manage the stockpiles to keep them not mixed with the useful ones? There are 157 kinds of seeds and I'm not manually sorting all this mess multiple times just to keep simple stockpiles of seeds SANE.
5. Is there any other use that I'm not seeing here?
6. If they can't be traded nor have another use, how can I dispose of them more or less automatically so they stop eating my FPS and stop messing with my Stocks?

**Version:** 0.50 (Steam).

**Which are the so-called useless seeds?**

As said previously, [the ones listed by the wiki](https://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/Seed#Seed_List)  with the columns "Edible raw", "Cookable", "Farmable" and "Oil Seed" as "No":

```
E = Edible Raw
C = Cookable
F = Farmable
V = Vermin Edible
O = Oil Seed
# = Raws/Menu Order

Seed type                   E   C   F   V   O    #

Single-grain wheat seeds    No  Yes Yes Yes No  001
Two-grain wheat seeds       No  Yes Yes Yes No  002
Soft wheat seeds            No  Yes Yes Yes No  003
Hard wheat seeds            No  Yes Yes Yes No  004
Spelt seeds                 No  Yes Yes Yes No  005
Barley seeds                No  Yes Yes Yes No  006
Buckwheat seeds             No  Yes Yes Yes No  007
Oats seeds                  No  Yes Yes Yes No  008
Alfalfa seeds               No  Yes Yes Yes No  009
Rye seeds                   No  Yes Yes Yes No  010
Sorghum seeds               No  Yes Yes Yes No  011
Rice                        No  Yes Yes Yes No  012
Maize                       No  Yes Yes Yes No  013
Quinoa seeds                No  Yes Yes Yes No  014
Kaniwa seeds                No  Yes Yes Yes No  015
Bitter vetch seeds          No  Yes Yes Yes No  016
Pendant amaranth seeds      No  Yes Yes Yes No  017
Blood amaranth seeds        No  Yes Yes Yes No  018
Purple amaranth seeds       No  Yes Yes Yes No  019
Red spinach seeds           No  Yes Yes Yes No  020
Elephant-head amaranth seedsNo  Yes Yes Yes No  021
Pearl millet                No  Yes Yes Yes No  022
White millet                No  Yes Yes Yes No  023
Finger millet               No  Yes Yes Yes No  024
Foxtail millet              No  Yes Yes Yes No  025
Fonio                       No  Yes Yes Yes No  026
Teff                        No  Yes Yes Yes No  027
Flax seeds                  Yes Yes Yes Yes Yes 028
Jute seeds                  No  No  Yes No  No  029
Hemp seeds                  Yes Yes Yes Yes Yes 030
Cotton seeds                Yes Yes Yes Yes Yes 031
Ramie seeds                 No  No  Yes No  No  032
Kenaf seeds                 Yes Yes Yes Yes Yes 033
Papyrus sedge seeds         No  No  Yes No  No  034
Artichoke seeds             No  No  Yes Yes No  035
Asparagus seeds             No  No  Yes Yes No  036
Bambara groundnut           Yes Yes Yes Yes No  037
String bean                 No  Yes Yes Yes No  038
Broad bean                  No  Yes Yes Yes No  039
Beet seeds                  No  No  Yes No  No  040
Bitter melon seeds          No  No  Yes No  No  041
Cabbage seeds               No  No  Yes No  No  042
Caper seeds                 No  No  Yes No  No  043
Carrot seeds                No  Yes Yes Yes No  044
Cassava seeds               No  No  Yes No  No  045
Celery seeds                No  No  Yes No  No  046
Chickpea                    No  Yes Yes Yes No  047
Chicory seeds               No  No  Yes No  No  048
Cowpea                      No  Yes Yes Yes No  049
Cucumber seeds              No  No  Yes No  No  050
Eggplant seeds              Yes Yes Yes Yes No  051
Garden cress seeds          No  No  Yes No  No  052
Garlic seeds                No  Yes Yes Yes No  053
Horned melon seeds          No  No  Yes No  No  054
Leek seeds                  No  No  Yes No  No  055
Lentil                      No  Yes Yes Yes No  056
Lettuce seeds               Yes Yes Yes No  No  057
Mung bean                   No  Yes Yes Yes No  058
Muskmelon seeds             No  No  Yes No  No  059
Onion seeds                 No  No  Yes No  No  060
Parsnip seeds               No  Yes Yes Yes No  061
Peas                        No  Yes Yes Yes No  062
Peanuts                     Yes Yes Yes Yes No  063
Pepper seeds                No  No  Yes No  No  064
Potato seeds                No  No  Yes No  No  065
Radish seeds                No  No  Yes No  No  066
Red beans                   No  Yes Yes Yes No  067
Rhubarb seeds               No  No  Yes No  No  068
Soybean                     No  Yes Yes Yes No  069
Spinach seeds               No  No  Yes No  No  070
Squash seeds                No  No  Yes No  No  071
Sweet potato seeds          No  No  Yes No  No  072
Taro seeds                  No  No  Yes No  No  073
Tomato seeds                No  Yes Yes Yes No  074
Tomatillo seeds             No  Yes Yes Yes No  075
Turnip seeds                No  No  Yes No  No  076
Urad beans                  No  Yes Yes Yes No  077
Watermelon seeds            No  No  Yes No  No  078
Winter melon seeds          No  No  Yes No  No  079
Lesser yam seeds            No  No  Yes No  No  080
Long yam seeds              No  No  Yes No  No  081
Purple yam seeds            No  No  Yes No  No  082
White yam seeds             No  No  Yes No  No  083
Passion fruit seeds         No  No  Yes No  No  084
Grape seeds                 No  No  Yes No  No  085
Cranberry seeds             No  No  Yes No  No  086
Bilberry seeds              No  No  Yes No  No  087
Blueberry seeds             No  No  Yes No  No  088
Blackberry seeds            No  No  Yes No  No  089
Raspberry seeds             No  No  Yes No  No  090
Pineapple seeds             No  No  Yes Yes No  091
Abaca seeds                 No  No  No  Yes No  092
Banana seeds                No  No  No  Yes No  093
Carambola seeds             No  No  No  Yes No  094
Cashews                     No  No  No  Yes No  095
Coffee beans                No  No  No  No  No  096
Durian seeds                No  Yes No  Yes No  097
Guava seeds                 No  No  No  Yes No  098
Papaya seeds                No  No  No  Yes No  099
Paradise nuts               No  No  No  Yes No  100
Rambutan seeds              No  Yes No  Yes No  101
Tea seeds                   No  No  No  Yes No  102
Avocado pits                No  No  No  Yes No  103
Lime seeds                  No  No  No  Yes No  104
Pomelo seeds                No  No  No  Yes No  105
Citron seeds                No  No  No  Yes No  106
Orange seeds                No  No  No  Yes No  107
Bitter orange seeds         No  No  No  Yes No  108
Finger lime seeds           No  No  No  Yes No  109
Round lime seeds            No  No  No  Yes No  110
Desert lime seeds           No  No  No  Yes No  111
Kumquat seeds               No  No  No  Yes No  112
Custard-apple seeds         No  No  No  Yes No  113
Date palm seeds             No  No  No  Yes No  114
Lychee seeds                No  No  No  Yes No  115
Macadamia nuts              Yes Yes No  Yes No  116
Olive pits                  No  No  No  Yes No  117
Pomegranate seeds           No  No  No  Yes No  118
Almonds                     Yes Yes No  Yes No  119
Apple seeds                 No  No  No  Yes No  120
Apricot pits                No  No  No  Yes No  121
Bayberry seeds              No  No  No  Yes No  122
Cherry pits                 No  No  No  Yes No  123
Ginkgo seeds                Yes Yes No  Yes No  124
Hazel nuts                  Yes Yes No  Yes No  125
Peach pits                  No  No  No  Yes No  126
Pear seeds                  No  No  No  Yes No  127
Pecans                      Yes Yes No  Yes No  128
Persimmon seeds             No  No  No  Yes No  129
Plum pits                   No  No  No  Yes No  130
Sand pear seeds             No  No  No  Yes No  131
Walnuts                     Yes Yes No  Yes No  132
Plump helmet spawn          No  Yes Yes Yes No  133
Pig tail seeds              No  Yes Yes Yes No  134
Cave wheat seeds            No  Yes Yes Yes No  135
Sweet pod seeds             No  Yes Yes Yes No  136
Rock nuts                   Yes Yes Yes Yes Yes 137
Muck root seeds             No  No  Yes No  No  138
Bloated tuber seeds         No  No  Yes No  No  139
Prickle berry seeds         No  Yes Yes Yes No  140
Strawberry seeds            No  Yes Yes Yes No  141
Longland grass seeds        No  Yes Yes Yes No  142
Rat weed seeds              No  Yes Yes Yes No  143
Fisher berry seeds          No  Yes Yes Yes No  144
Rope reed seeds             No  Yes Yes Yes No  145
Dimple cup spawn            No  Yes Yes Yes No  146
Blade weed seeds            No  Yes Yes Yes No  147
Hide root seeds             No  Yes Yes Yes No  148
Sliver barb seeds           No  Yes Yes Yes No  149
Sun berry seeds             No  Yes Yes Yes No  150
Whip vine seeds             No  Yes Yes Yes No  151
Acorns                      Yes Yes No  Yes No  152
Acacia seeds                No  Yes No  Yes No  153
Chestnuts                   Yes Yes No  Yes No  154
Candlenuts                  No  Yes No  Yes No  155
Mango pits                  No  No  No  Yes No  156
Cacao beans                 No  Yes No  No  No  157
```

Comment: You could always smash them with a drawbridge

Comment: @user1337 I never used one. [The wiki says I cannot place a stockpile on a drawbridge](https://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/Dwarven_atom_smasher#Smashing_against_the_ground), so I cannot place the useless seeds below it.

Comment: Posted it as an answer. The trick is just to use a zone and not a stockpile. The wiki page points it out too as it turns out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tool I recommend is a [dwarven atom smasher](https://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2014:Dwarven_atom_smasher).

First, you designate a 1x1 [dumping zone](https://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/Garbage_dump)

Second, and not necessarily in this order, you build a drawbridge that slams down on said tile.

Upon smashing down the drawbridge onto the tile, you obliterate anything smaller than an elephant (all items and any creature up to a size of 1200000cm³). This can remove excess items, pets, population, invaders and consequently improve performance.

Note: If items end up being dumped onto an open drawbridge, raising the drawbridge will instead launch the items (and dwarves) in whatever direction the bridge closed.

EDIT: To answer the "useless seeds" bit:
I copy-pasted the source seed into excel and filtered by your criteria. All of the resulting seeds are tree seeds, i.e. abaca, apple, apricot, avocado, banana and so on. Trees grow on their own and there's no tree planting functionality in the game. To answer your question, you are right in that the seeds that match your criteria serve no purpose and can be smashed.

Comment: So, the seeds I mentioned really can't be sold/don't have value for trading? I really will lose nothing worthy by dumping them?

Comment: Generally yes, although I'm not sure which exact seeds you have in mind. There are very few farmable plants that are noteworthy (like papyrus and sun berries) as the 6 underground plants can generally achieve the same results. Not sure about version 50.x but the only advantage of farming above ground is that those plants can be planted year round, which gets excessive anyway.

Comment: "I'm not sure which exact seeds you have in mind". I edited the question to add a plaintext version of the table shown in the wiki. Does this helps?